実行時に check failure が出る: Stack around the variable 'new_one' was corrupted
C言語での質問です。以下のコードを実行するとエラーが出ます。
一部分(1・2文字程度)修正するだけでエラーを無くせるとのことなのですが、Geminiにきいたり自分なりに調べたりしたのですがどうしてもやり方がわかりません。
学校の課題などではないので掲示板に載せることは問題ないものになります。
ご助力いただけますと幸いです。よろしくお願いします。
エラーメッセージ:
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'new_one' was corrupted.

現状のコード:
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#define READ_SIZE (4096)
#define NEXT_SIZE (1600)
#define NEXT_OFFSET (32)
#define PHY_HEADER_SIZE (14)
#define IPV6_HEADER_SIZE (40)
#define ARP_PACKET  (1)
#define IPv4_PACKET (2)
#define IPv6_PACKET (3)
#define MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE (1512)

unsigned char buf[2][READ_SIZE];

unsigned char ADDR(int t_adr)
{
    int mem = t_adr / READ_SIZE;
    mem %= 2;
    int l_adr = t_adr & 0xFFF;

    return buf[mem][l_adr];
}

int chk_protcol(int t_adr)
{
    int protcol = 0;

    if ((ADDR(t_adr + 12 + 0) == 0x08) && (ADDR(t_adr + 12 + 1) == 0x06)) {
        protcol = ARP_PACKET;
    }else if((ADDR(t_adr + 12 + 0) == 0x86) && (ADDR(t_adr + 12 + 1) == 0xdd)){
        protcol = IPv6_PACKET;
    }
    else if ((ADDR(t_adr + 12 + 0) == 0x08) && (ADDR(t_adr + 12 + 1) == 0x00)) {
        protcol = IPv4_PACKET;
    }

    return protcol;
}

int chk_ether_tail(int t_adr)
{
    int ad_size = 0;


    for (int jj = 0; jj < 32; jj++) {

        if (ADDR(t_adr + jj + 0) == 0x20 && ADDR(t_adr + jj + 1) == 0x20 && ADDR(t_adr + jj + 2) == 0x20 && ADDR(t_adr + jj + 3) == 0x20) {

            ad_size = jj + 3 ;
            break;
        }

    }

    return ad_size;
}

struct st_p {
    int pkt_number;
    int pkt_len;
    unsigned char mem[MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE];
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<st_p> pkt_list;
    pkt_list.clear();

   FILE *fp = fopen("a.pcapng", "rb");


    int flag = 1;
    int readnum = 0;
    int endadress = 0;
    int crt_adr = 0;
    int crt_mem = 0;
    int f_found = 0;
    int ex_len;
    int ex_adr;
    int ex_tgt;
    int num_packet = 0;
    int num_etc = 0;
    int t_message = 0 ;
    unsigned char mess[2048];
    size_t t = fread(buf[crt_mem], 1, READ_SIZE, fp);

    crt_mem += 1;

    crt_mem %= 2;
    readnum += 1;

    endadress = (int)t + (readnum - 1) * READ_SIZE;

    int max_len= 0;

    while (endadress > crt_adr ) {

        int len = endadress - crt_adr;

        if (len < NEXT_SIZE && flag == 1) {

            t = fread(buf[crt_mem], 1, READ_SIZE, fp);

            if (t != READ_SIZE) {
                flag = 0;
            }

            crt_mem += 1;

            crt_mem %= 2;
            readnum += 1;

            endadress = (int)t + (readnum - 1) * READ_SIZE;

        }
        else {

            if (f_found == 0) {

                if ((ADDR(crt_adr + 0) != 0xFF) && (ADDR(crt_adr + 1) == 0xFF) && (ADDR(crt_adr + 2) == 0xFF) && (ADDR(crt_adr + 3) == 0xFF) && (ADDR(crt_adr + 4) == 0xFF) && (ADDR(crt_adr + 5) == 0xFF) && (ADDR(crt_adr + 6) == 0xFF) && (ADDR(crt_adr + 7) != 0xFF)) {

                    printf("%d ARP Locked 60 %x\n", t_message++,crt_adr);
                    f_found = 1;
                    crt_adr += 60;
                    crt_adr += 1;
                    crt_adr += NEXT_OFFSET;
                }
                else {
                    crt_adr += 1;
                }

            }
            else {

                int protcol = chk_protcol(crt_adr);


                if(protcol == ARP_PACKET){

                    if ((ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 7)) == 0x01){

                        int ad_size = 0;
                        int adr_tail = crt_adr + 42 + 14;


                        if (ADDR(adr_tail+ 0) == 0x20 && ADDR(adr_tail  + 1) == 0x20 && ADDR(adr_tail + 2) == 0x20 && ADDR(adr_tail + 3) == 0x20) {
                            ad_size = 18;
                        }
                        if (ADDR(adr_tail + 4) == 0x5C) {
                            ad_size = 18;
                        }
                        for (int hh = 0; hh < 2048; hh++) {
                            mess[hh] = ADDR(crt_adr + hh);
                        }
                        crt_adr += NEXT_OFFSET + 42 + ad_size ;
                       
                        if (ad_size == 0) {

                            crt_adr += 2;

                            printf("%d ARP1 42 %x\n", t_message++, crt_adr);

                            if (crt_adr % 4 != 0) {
                                if (crt_adr % 4 == 3) {
                                    crt_adr >>= 2;
                                    crt_adr += 1;
                                    crt_adr <<= 2;
                                }
                                else {
                                    crt_adr >>= 2;
                                    crt_adr <<= 2;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("%d ARP1 60 %x\n", t_message++, crt_adr);
                        }
                 
                    }
                    else if ((ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 7)) == 0x02)
                    {

                        for (int hh = 0; hh < 2048; hh++) {
                            mess[hh] = ADDR(crt_adr + hh);
                        }
                        int ad_size = 0;
                        int adr_tail = crt_adr + 42 + 14;
                        if (ADDR(adr_tail + 4) == 0x5C) {
                            ad_size = 18;
                        }

                        crt_adr += 42 + ad_size;
                        crt_adr += NEXT_OFFSET;
                        if (ad_size == 0) {
                            crt_adr += 2;
                        }
                       

                        printf("%d ARP2 %d %x \n", t_message++,42 + ad_size, crt_adr);

                        if(ad_size == 0){
                            if (crt_adr % 4 != 0) {
                                if (crt_adr % 4 == 3) {
                                    crt_adr >>= 2;
                                    crt_adr += 1;
                                    crt_adr <<= 2;
                                }
                                else {
                                    crt_adr >>= 2;

                                    crt_adr <<= 2;
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }
                   
                }
                else if(protcol == IPv6_PACKET || protcol == IPv4_PACKET ) {

                    if ((ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 0) & 0xF0) == 0x40) {

                        unsigned short len = ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 2 + 0) * 256 + ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 2 + 1);
                        int packet_len = len + PHY_HEADER_SIZE  ;

                        if (max_len < packet_len) {
                            max_len = packet_len;
                        }

                        ex_len = len + PHY_HEADER_SIZE;
                        ex_adr = crt_adr;
                        ex_tgt = crt_adr + ex_len;

                        int ad_size = 0;
                        int adr_tail = crt_adr + packet_len;

                        ad_size = chk_ether_tail(adr_tail);

                        if (len == 40 && (ADDR(crt_adr + 40 + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 6) == 0x5C ) && ad_size == 0)
                        {
                            ad_size = 6;
                        }
                        if (len == 32 && (ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 31 + 15) == 0x5c) && ad_size == 0) {

                            ad_size = 14;
                        }

                        packet_len += NEXT_OFFSET + 2 + ad_size;

                        char packet[256];

                        if (ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 9) == 17) {
                            sprintf(packet, "%s", "UDP");
                        }
                        else if (ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 9) == 6) {
                            sprintf(packet, "%s", "TCP");
                        }
                        else if (ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 9) == 2) {
                            sprintf(packet, "%s", "ICMPV2");
                        }
                        else {
                            sprintf(packet, "%s", "ETC");
                            num_etc += 1;
                        }
                        if (strcmp(packet, "UDP") == 0 || strcmp(packet, "UDP") == 0) {
                            st_p new_one;

                            for (int hh = 0; hh < max_len ; hh++) {
                                new_one.mem[hh] = ADDR(crt_adr + hh);
                            }

                            pkt_list.push_back(new_one);
                        }

                        printf("%d IPv4 %s %d %x\n", t_message++ , packet ,ex_len,crt_adr);

                        num_packet += 1;

                        unsigned char tcp = ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 10);

                        crt_adr += packet_len;


                        if (crt_adr % 4 != 0) {

                            if (crt_adr % 4 == 3) {
                                crt_adr >>= 2;
                                crt_adr += 1;
                                crt_adr <<= 2;
                            }
                            else {
                                crt_adr >>= 2;
                                crt_adr <<= 2;
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    else if( (ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 0) & 0xF0) == 0x60)
                    {
                        unsigned short len = ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 2 + 0 + 2) * 256 + ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 2 + 1 + 2);
                        int packet_len = len + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + IPV6_HEADER_SIZE;

                        if (max_len < packet_len) {
                            max_len = packet_len;
                        }

                        ex_len = packet_len;
                        ex_adr = crt_adr;
                        ex_tgt = crt_adr + ex_len;

                        int ad_size = 0;
                        int adr_tail = crt_adr + packet_len;

                        ad_size = chk_ether_tail(adr_tail);

                        packet_len += NEXT_OFFSET +2 + ad_size;

                        char packet[256];
                        if (ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 6) == 17) {
                            sprintf(packet, "%s", "UDP");
                        }
                        else if ((ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 6) == 6)) {
                            sprintf(packet, "%s", "TCP");
                        }
                        else if ((ADDR(crt_adr + PHY_HEADER_SIZE + 6) == 58)) {
                            sprintf(packet, "%s", "ICMPv6");
                        }else{
                            sprintf(packet, "%s", "ETC");
                            num_etc += 1;
                        }
                       
                        if (strcmp(packet, "UDP") == 0 || strcmp(packet, "UDP") == 0) {
                            st_p new_one;
                            for (int hh = 0; hh < max_len; hh++) {
                                new_one.mem[hh] = ADDR(crt_adr + hh);
                            }
                            pkt_list.push_back(new_one);
                        }

                        num_packet += 1;

                        crt_adr += packet_len;

                        printf("%d IPv6 %s %d %x\n", t_message++, packet, ex_len, crt_adr);

                        if (crt_adr % 4 != 0) {
                            if (crt_adr % 4 == 3) {
                                crt_adr >>= 2;
                                crt_adr += 1;
                                crt_adr <<= 2;
                            }
                            else {
                                crt_adr >>= 2;
                                crt_adr <<= 2;
                            }
   
                        }

                    }
                    else {

                        printf(" %d Unknown %d,%d,%x %d\n", t_message , ex_len, ex_adr, crt_adr,ADDR(crt_adr));

                    }

                }
                else {

                    if ((endadress - crt_adr) <= 0x50) {
                        crt_adr = endadress;
                    }
                    else {

                        printf(" %d Unknown2 %x %d %x ,%x\n", t_message, crt_adr, ADDR(crt_adr), (ADDR(crt_adr + 12 + 0)), (ADDR(crt_adr + 12 + 1)));
                        printf("AA\n");
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

    printf(" %d,%d,%d,%d\n", endadress, num_packet, max_len, num_etc);
    fclose(fp);

    pkt_list.clear();

}


C言語ではなくC++では？ VS2022でC言語(拡張子を.c)にしたらIntelliSenseでエラー表示され、C++(拡張子を.cpp)ならば問題は無かったのですが。それから何をするためのプログラムなのか、サンプルのテストデータや問題の再現手順の詳細とか、どんな結果が出て欲しいがこんな問題がある、といった情報を追記してみてください。使うファイル名から PcapNg ファイルの解析のようですが、Wiresharkの一部のtshark.cの改造とかでは駄目なのでしょうか？ 【C言語】ネットワークアナライザ「Wireshark」とは, Pcapngを読んでみる, PcapNg解析入門, Wireshark の CLI 版 TShark を試してみる。

コメントありがとうございます。詳しく理解しておらず申し訳ないです。個人的にはバッファオーバーフローが起きているのかと思っておりfor文の何処かを一部編集したらエラーが消えるのかなと思ったのですが。。見当違いでしたら申し訳ないです。

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGSを指定しているのでしたら、Visual Studioを使っているのでしょうから、Debugモードでビルドしてデバッグ実行してみれば問題の箇所で止まるとか、最後まで実行してエラー表示があるとしても、その最後にブレークポイントを入れておいて状態を調べるとか出来るのでは？ それから他の人に問題を再現・調査して欲しいならコメントしたようにサンプルのテストデータや再現手順とかを提示した方が良いでしょう。推測したり準備する手間や時間が削減出来るし推測が違ったりすると双方の時間の無駄になるので。

UDP パケットの内容をコピーしている部分 for (int hh = 0; hh < max_len ; hh++) { new_one.mem[hh] = ADDR(crt_adr + hh); } ですが、new_one.mem は unsigned char mem[MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE] と定義されていますので、max_len の値が MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE よりも大きい場合は範囲外アクセスが発生することになります。

まだ始めたばかりで右も左も分からず質問の内容もうまく伝えられておらず申し訳ないです。出題者より、本来読み込んでいい範囲以上に読み込んでしまう？からこのようなエラーが出るから読み込んでいい範囲内に範囲を設定すればいいとのヒントはいただきました。つまりfor文の=や>の範囲設定が誤っているからその辺りを1・2文字修正すればエラーは無くなると言った意味だと思い何時間も試行錯誤してみたのですが解決せず。。
